# Hyperspectral files in the ENVI format?

Tags: image-processing, import, data

Have any of you had the pleasure of reading geospatial / hyperspectral files in the ENVI format? Headers that describe the data here,

https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/enviheaderfiles.html

which are basically a giant mass of measurements in a raster.

There are some solutions for other scientific computing environments, but nothing for Mathematica that I can find. Before I piece together a parser I figured I would ask the hive-mind for possible solutions.

Edit: Here's two small demo files+headers. The format itself is pretty simple and the data can be grabbed with `BinaryReadList` no problem, for hackery purposes. Ultimately it would be nice to have a nicely integrated package.

https://files.flipphillips.com/index.php/s/PmbYBcBeZmZZGrd

Comment: Can you link a complete sample file as well?

Comment: @marcob Yes- I will try to find a smaller-ish one. All of mine are 9-10GB and on our NAS.

Comment: @MarcoB - there you is. Pretty straightforward for me to just read the raw data I have, since I know how it was gathered, etc. But in the long term it would be nice to have a 'real' package for doing so of course. Was wondering if there are others out there similarly situated as me. (Note too, even though that's generally a geospatial format, all my data is of fruit and veggies, from some friends: https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.35.00B256